# How to register new upkeep on chainlink without using GUI?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, etherscan, ethers.js, chainlink

I have an application where I need to register new upkeep without using the provided [GUI](https://keepers.chain.link/rinkeby).  [Here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/overview/), under **Keeper Contract** section I found we can do that by interacting with **register** method in [UpkeepRegistrationRequests.sol](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.7/UpkeepRegistrationRequests.sol) contract. But I cannot find the address on the Rinkeby network or any other reference on how to do it.

I want to register new upkeep either through my own contract or by using frameworks like ethers or web3 if I get ABI and address to interact with.

P.S. I am sorry if this is trivial. I am new to this space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample code to programmatically register an upkeep.
https://gist.github.com/stone4419/4b5129e184a20f6f85b2cc613381d54f

The default contract ids are for Kovan. You can find the Rinkeby or other testnet or mainnet values here:
LINK tokens: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/
Keepers registry: https://keepers.chain.link/rinkeby
Test LINK faucet: https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby

Comment: It works!! Just want to know what is SOURCE = 110;

Comment: From the source code comments: “source application sending this request”
It’s a way for us to track how the registration was created.